# Number of coin tosses to choose between 3 desserts

Tags: probability

Alice is in a restaurant trying to decide between 3 desserts. How can she choose one of three desserts with equal probability with the help of a fair coin?

I see that she could just take TH, HT and TT to be the events shes choose desserts 1,2 and 3 respectively and HH be the event she repeats the toss of 2 coins. However, I now was wondering what would be the expected number of coin tosses before she chooses one of the desserts with equal probability?

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive argument:

At the start "useful" outcomes are TH, HT, TT, while HH is "unuseful."
Then probability of a useful outcome on each toss is 3/4, so the
mean waiting time for the first useful outcome is 4/3.

From there on until the next hit, there only two "useful" outcomes, ... and so on.

Answer: $4(1/3 + 1/2 + 1).$

I'll leave a rigorous mathematical discussion to you.
Maybe you want to look at a discussion of the 'coupon collecting problem' for that.